# How to add child nodes in a json object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am building a JSON file dynamically. I want to add a JSON array in the JSON object. The JSON looks like-

```
{"name":"Root",
  "children":[
   {"name":"child1"},
   {"name":"child2"}
  ]}
```

Now, I want to add -

```
[{"name":"child11"},{"name":"child12"}]
```

under "child1" object. How to do it? I have also tried keeping blank children object while creating the original JSON object, but JSON parser doesn't keep those empty children block. In current scenario, when I am using push() function to add new child it throws exception. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Edit1: I think I didn't made myself clear enough. I have researched SO before posting this question, and I guess this is not a duplicate question. My target JSON is -

```js
{
  "name": "Root",
  "children": [{
      "name": "child1",
   "children": [{
  {"name": "child11"},
  {"name": "child12"}
   }]
    },
    {
      "name": "child2",
   "children": [{
  {"name": "child21"},
  {"name": "child22"}
   }]
    }
  ]
};
```

Here is the code snippet that I am trying to run -

```js
flare = {
  "name": "Root",
  "children": [{
      "name": "child1",
   "children": [{
  {"name": "child11"},
  {"name": "child12"}
   }]
    },
    {
      "name": "child2",
   "children": [{
  {"name": "child21"},
  {"name": "child22"}
   }]
    }
  ]
};
var updatedJson = twoLevelSelection(flare);
function twoLevelSelection(json){
 var root = flare.name;
 var string_json = '';
 string_json = '{"name": "'+root+'","children": [';
 flare.children.forEach(
 function(d){
  string_json = string_json+ '{"name":"'+d.name+'","children":[]},';
 }
 );
 string_json = string_json.substring(0,string_json.length-1);
 string_json = string_json + ']}';
 return JSON.parse(string_json);
}
// data is the original data.i.e - flare
// d is the clicked node, under which children to be added
function traverse(data,d){
var queue = [];
var next = data;
while(next){
 if(next.children){
  next.children.forEach(
  function(k){
   queue.push(k);
  }
  )
 }
 if(queue[0].name==d.name){
  alert(queue[0].children);
  //d.children = queue[0].children;
  var child_string='';
  var child_array = [];
  queue[0].children.forEach(
  function(j){
   child_string = '{"name": "'+j.name+'"}';
   child_array.push(child_string);
  }
  );
  console.log(child_array);
  d.children = [...child_array];
  console.log(updatedJson);
  //update(updatedJson);
  break;
 }else{
  next= queue.shift();
 }
}
}
```

The traverse() will be called on a click event.
Sorry, for not providing clarity at first place. Thanks!

Comment: new account - same question

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org/), is a string.

Comment: @messerbill Should post the link as well

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: the question was already closed i cannot find it anymore - this was some days ago

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to accomplish that.

This code snippet has a function called `addElements` which find the target and adds the new elements to the `children` array.

```js
var obj = {
  "name": "Root",
  "children": [{
      "name": "child1"
    },
    {
      "name": "child2"
    }
  ]
};


var newArray = [
   { "name": "child11"}, 
   { "name": "child12"}
];

var addElements = function(target, array) {
  obj.children.forEach(function(child) {
    if (child.name === target) {
      child['children'] = [...(child['children'] || []), ...newArray];
      return;
    }
  });
};

addElements('child1', newArray);


console.log(obj);
```

See? now your `obj.childre[0].children` array contains the new elements.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I wasn't clear about my query. Actually,  I want to add new children under "child1" not under "root". Please find the edit and the code above.

Comment: Thank you @ele. Actually I took a different approach to achieve the goal. Your solution works great. Thanks!

Comment: @KaustavRoy great.  An accepted answer would be nice :-)